# how to use explode or any other php explode look like -

Tags: php

I have a variables get from different pages, it's an SMS based APPLICATION.

```
$message = $_GET['message'];// Message content
                            // Message = LIVE DEMO 123456789 ;
```

Now i want these 3 words in different variables, `DEMO` and `live` is my keyword and `12345679` is value and i want to cross check this value from different table then insert into another table.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking what it looks like to use `explode` in php? If so, here is how it would work with your example.

```
$message = $_GET['message'];
$results = explode(' ', $message);
```

This returns the array ...

```
Array
(
    [0] => LIVE
    [1] => DEMO
    [2] => 123456789
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be wanting the [list](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) function

```
list($firstPart, $secondPart, $thirdPart) = explode(" ", $_GET['message']);
```

Longhand

```
$partArry = explode(" ", $_GET['message']);
$firstPart = $partArray[0];
$secondPart = $partArray[1];
$firstPart = $partArray[2];
```